# What kind of expression is 'appBar : AppBar( ' in Dart language

Tags: flutter, dart, syntax

What are those entities separated by colon and what kind of relation between them.For instance:

`return Scaffold( appBar: AppBar( title: Text(widget.title)`
),

Comment: Class "Scaffold" is taking the named parameter "appBar".  Class "AppBar", in turn, takes the named parameter "title".  Which accepts a "Text" object.  You can read more about named parameters in Dart here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/dart_programming/dart_programming_optional_named_parameter.htm

Comment: You should read [The Dart Language Tour](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Left side** of the **colon** is **named parameters** or properties of the Widget. **right** side of the colon is the **value for the parameter**. Here AppBar() is an object as value of the named parameter.